# Python TCP Payload Duplication - Passing through data to multiple endpoints concurrently

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-multithreading

this is my first post here!

My goal is to duplicate the payload of a unidirectional TCP stream and send this payload to multiple endpoints concurrently. I have a working prototype written in Python, however I am new to Python, and to Socket programming. Ideally the solution is capable of running in both Windows and *nix environments.

This prototype works, however it creates a new send TCP connection for each Buffer length (currently set to 4096 bytes). The main problem with this is I will eventually run out of local ports to send from, and ideally I would like the data to pass from each single incoming TCP stream to one single TCP stream out (for each endpoint). The incoming data can vary from less than 1024 bytes to hundreds of megabytes.

At the moment a new outgoing TCP stream is initiated for every 4096 bytes. I am not sure if the problem is in my implementation of threading, or if I have missed something else really obvious.

In my research I have found that select() could help, however I am not sure if it would be appropriate because I may need to process some of the incoming data and respond to the sending client for certain cases in the future.

Here is the code I have so far (some of the code variations I have tried are commented out):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#One way TCP payload duplication
import sys
import threading
from socket import *
bufsize = 4096
host= ''

# Methods:  
#handles sending the data to the endpoints  
def send(endpoint,port,data):
    sendSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    #sendSocket.setblocking(1)
    sendSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    #sendport = sendSocket.getsockname
    #print sendport
    try:
        sendSocket.connect((endpoint, port))
        sendSocket.sendall(data)
    except IOError as msg:
        print "Send Failed. Error Code: " + str(msg[0]) + ' Message: ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()  

#handles threading for sending data to endpoints
def forward(service, ENDPOINT_LIST, port, data):
    #for each endpoint in the endpoint list start a new send thread
    for endpoint in ENDPOINT_LIST:
        print "Forwarding data for %s from %s:%s to %s:%s" % (service,host,port,endpoint,port)
        #send(endpoint,port,data)
        ethread = threading.Thread(target=send, args=(endpoint,port,data))
        ethread.start()

#handles threading for incoming clients 
def clientthread(conn,service,ENDPOINT_LIST,port):
    while True:
        #receive data form client
        data = conn.recv(bufsize)
        if not data:
            break
        cthread = threading.Thread(target=forward, args=(service, ENDPOINT_LIST, port, data))
        cthread.start()
    #no data? then close the connection
    conn.close()

#handles listening to sockets for incoming connections
def listen(service, ENDPOINT_LIST, port):
    #create the socket
    listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    #Allow reusing addresses - I think this is important to stop local ports getting eaten up by never-ending tcp streams that don't close
    listenSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    #try to bind the socket to host and port
    try:
        listenSocket.bind((host, port))
    #display an error message if you can't
    except IOError as msg:
        print "Bind Failed. Error Code: " + str(msg[0]) + ' Message: ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()
    #start listening on the socket
    listenSocket.listen(10)
    print "Service %s on port %s is listening" %(service,port)
    while True:
        #wait to accept a connection
        conn, addr = listenSocket.accept()
        print 'Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]) + ' on port ' + str(port)
        #start new thread for each connection
        lthread = threading.Thread(target=clientthread , args=(conn,service,ENDPOINT_LIST,port))
        lthread.start()
    #If no data close the connection
    listenSocket.close()

service = "Dumb-one-way-tcp-service-name1"  
ENDPOINT_LIST = ["192.168.1.100","192.168.1.200"]
port = 55551    
listen(service,ENDPOINT_LIST,port)
```

I have looked into other libraries to try to achieve my goal, including using:

- Twisted
- Asyncore
- Scapy

However I found them quite complicated for my modest needs and programming skill level.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I could refine the approach I have, or any other ways this goal could be achieved, please let me know!

Comment: There are several solutions which are easier or more complicated, depending on the kind of synchronization needed.  Say you will receive 10MB and want to relay it to 3 destinations.  Say destination number 3 is slow in accepting its flow of data.  Do you want to receive all 10MB fast and send it immediately to the other two destinations, and buffer it in memory for the 3rd?  Or is it ok (or even better) to slow down the whole thing, i.e. receive and pass on the 10MB at the speed of the slowest connection?

Comment: @ArminRigo, I think syncronization is important. I do want to accept the data fast. If the endpoint has the capacity the forwarded stream should be sent at the same speed it came in at, however if an endpoint is slower than another (which isnn't likely to be a problem for me) it would be nice for it to buffer  the payload before it gets sent. I thought this would be the case in Python that it would buffer the incoming payload in RAM as it tries to send it out - or do I need to explicitly tell it to buffer it somewhere? And do you think buffering it somewhere could help my many outgoing issues?

Answer (score 0):

In short, your question is there are not enough ports, right? It seems you didn't close socket after sending. Try this in `send()`:

```
...
except IOError as msg:
    print "Send Failed. Error Code: " + str(msg[0]) + ' Message: ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit() 
finally:
    sendSocket.close()
```

Comment: That is probably a good idea to close the connection in a finally case, but it didn't help to stop a new outgoing TCP connection for each buffer length

Comment: @BeSure So you don't want to send traffic every time in a new connectin?

Comment: No I don't for every incoming connection I want to pipe the payload of that into a single TCP connection to each endpoint. The payload can vary up to hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: @BeSure I think for each endpoint there should be a TCP connection. One TCP connection cann't be connected to several endpoints. Hope my understanding is right.

Comment: Just to clarify I mean one connection for each ( eg for three endpoints three separate TCP connections but sending the same payload)

Comment: @BeSure So when there is payload, no matter how large it is, your code will create a new TCP connection and send it out. Is there problem in this?

Comment: That's how I want the code to work. For example if I receive an incoming stream, and the total size is 10MB, all I want to do is forward 10mb of data within that single stream to multiple endpoint- but with a single stream to each. Obviously  if there was an issue that caused the TCP connection to an endpoing to close, it would open another to continue. I don't see a problem in this, however I can't wait to buffer the whole stream length first, I have to start forwarding the payload as I receive it (or as close as possible). I thought this would be a simple I/O thing, but now I am not so sure

Comment: @BeSure Now I see your problem. Since you set bufsize in clientthread, socket will continue only after receiving so much data. If you want to speed up this procedure, I think you can try to decrease the bufsize.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, if you don't want to learn some more advanced framework like Twisted.

The closest to what you're doing: use threads, but you need to have one thread per outgoing connection --- and *not* per outgoing packet.  Create 3 `Queue.Queue` objects, and create 3 threads, passing to each one one of the `Queue` objects and one of the destinations.  Each thread opens a socket, and then in a loop, it gets the next string from its own `Queue` and sends it to the socket.  The clientthread (which can be just the main thread, a priori) receives data as strings, and puts each of these strings into all the Queues.  This way, the packets sent don't get out of order, as they could if you create one thread per packet.

The alternative is to avoid threads completely, and use `select()`.  It's a bit more mind-bending.  Basically you have only one big loop that starts with `select()`.  It needs careful management to pass the correct list of sockets to `select()`: you want the call to `select()` to wake up *either* when there is incoming data from the inbound socket, *or* if an outbound socket is both ready to send more and there is something more to send.  In this model you'd have 3 lists of strings; when you read incoming data you append it to all three lists; the `select()` call is passed the list of outbound sockets that have a non-empty list (so, more to send); and when sending, you must not use `sendall()` in this model but `send()`, and if less than the full string was sent, you must re-add the remainder to the beginning of the corresponding list.

Comment: I think Queue is the approach I want to take, I have tried to implement your suggestions, and I have the Queue's working, however I am not sure on how to structure the threading, I am still creating too many threads which fail for larger files, and I can't quite figure out why...